# Sequence of outputs by using pool starmap for parallel threads

Tags: python, parallel-processing, starmap

I am using `pool.starmap` for parallel running of my function as follows.

```
def func_parallel(arg_1):

  ## Compute two ouputs and return those two outputs
  ## output_1=function_1(arg1)
  ## output_2=function_2(arg1)
return output_1, output_2




file_name_1_list=[file_1, file_2]

pool = mp.Pool(2)

result_1, result_2= pool.starmap(func_parallel, [(file) for file in file_name_1_list])
pool.close()
```

**What I want with the above code:**

As I have two files in `file_name_1_list=[file_1, file_2]`,  and for each file, I should be getting two outputs.

I want that `output_1` should go into `result_1` and `output_2` should go into `result_2` for each of the files given as an argument to my parallel function via `starmap`

The `result_1` and `result_2` are lists.

How can I change the above code to achieve my desired results (`output_1` should go into `result_1` and `output_2` should go into `result_2` for each of the files given as an argument to my parallel function via `starmap`)

Comment: See: [How to unpack results from `Pool.map()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579727/9059420). Works the same with `.starmap()`.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks